# Can two $W$ bosons convert a proton into an antiproton by becoming two $W^+$ bosons?

Tags: standard-model, big-bang, electroweak

Would this process have been more or less likely in the high energy conditions around the time of the big bang?

Comment: Do you mean $p\to\overline{p}+2W^+$? If so, that violates $B-L$ conservation.

Comment: Yes. Interestingly violation of  B - L conservation can lead to a 4th massive neutrino .Perhaps this is dark matter !

Comment: The neutrino would have to come from antiproton becomes proton with 2 W minus bosons leaving no antimatter around after  the big bang.

Comment: Dark matter will be made of something stable. Are you positing a neutrino that doesn't oscillate with the first three flavours?

Comment: @J.G.  The neutrino produced by antimatter --> matter could be 5 times more massive than the first three flavours  (ratio of dark matter/matter is about 5/1). This might leave it completely out of phase with them.